# AWS Code Build artifact is missing one file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-codebuild

I have a code build instance which is building a `CDK` app in a MonoRepo into a dist folder. If I run `ls` in the folder after the build command it shows all files outputted buy the build but then the artefact produced is missing one of them, and I can't figure out why.

**Buildspec**

```json
{
  "version": "0.2",
  "phases": {
    "install": {
      "runtime-versions": {
        "nodejs": "latest"
      },
      "commands": [
        "n lts",
        "npm i -g npm@latest",
        "npm ci"
      ]
    },
    "build": {
      "commands": [
        "npm run build-front-end",
        "ls ./path/to/dist"
      ]
    }
  },
  "artifacts": {
    "files": [
      "path/to/dist/**/*"
    ]
  },
  "cache": {
    "paths": [
      "/root/.npm/**/*"
    ]
  }
}
```

The output of the `ls` command is:

```
DataStore.assets.json
DataStore.template.json
FrontEnd.assets.json
FrontEnd.template.json
Pipeline.assets.json
Pipeline.template.json
asset.1ebc9d3ac2033816c4abb63e4afd69d350b4aba8704cc9236b82ea520b74f4b0
asset.3fb6287214999ddeafa7cd0e3e58bc5144c8678bb720f3b5e45e8fd32f333eb3.zip
asset.5bc602ecde93c947efe5899ae355f999986a1acbe610b1c0b9c468d738857555
asset.6f15086578588c0f5f1cd712f8bb5688927f8e58e010630bfb53ec48a992dcc0
asset.7b1448c18435e2a9fd6dd739b24710af12127e39ce6a360d0e54584c57aec679
asset.9eb41a5505d37607ac419321497a4f8c21cf0ee1f9b4a6b29aa04301aea5c7fd
asset.b7f33614a69548d6bafe224d751a7ef238cde19097415e553fe8b63a4c8fd8a6
asset.faa3f939bd2f560adff4a880c2543a9c501ca978205ba00428f1a6ec00bad206
cdk.out
manifest.json
tree.json
```

Where as the asset is contains the following items:

```
DataStore.assets.json
DataStore.template.json
FrontEnd.assets.json
FrontEnd.template.json
Pipeline.assets.json
Pipeline.template.json
asset.3fb6287214999ddeafa7cd0e3e58bc5144c8678bb720f3b5e45e8fd32f333eb3.zip
asset.5bc602ecde93c947efe5899ae355f999986a1acbe610b1c0b9c468d738857555
asset.6f15086578588c0f5f1cd712f8bb5688927f8e58e010630bfb53ec48a992dcc0
asset.7b1448c18435e2a9fd6dd739b24710af12127e39ce6a360d0e54584c57aec679
asset.9eb41a5505d37607ac419321497a4f8c21cf0ee1f9b4a6b29aa04301aea5c7fd
asset.b7f33614a69548d6bafe224d751a7ef238cde19097415e553fe8b63a4c8fd8a6
asset.faa3f939bd2f560adff4a880c2543a9c501ca978205ba00428f1a6ec00bad206
cdk.out
manifest.json
tree.json
```

Comment: There isn't a lot to go off of here. Can you share more info, like what your Pipeline code looks like, and why you're expecting that asset? Is it the asset.1eb...4b0 you're expecting in your CodeBuild project but not seeing?

Comment: I know this isn’t a lot to go by, but this shouldn’t be up to the pipeline or anything else. The code build instance runs the build, and then it packages everything that’s in the `path/to/dist/**/*` location into a zip file. When I run a `ls` command in that folder the asset.1eb...4b0 file is there, but the zip directory code build emits doesn’t contain that file. But that shouldn’t be, because the `**\*` delimiter should select all files and subdirectories to be in the artifact.

Answer (score 0):

After some more investigation, I figured out that although not empty the directory doesn't actually contain a file, just nested directories. For some reason code build does not include this in its artifat. I personally think it should, but I guess that's out of my hand.